# Photodisintegration of deuterium

Tags: momentum, energy-conservation, nuclear-physics, binding-energy

The photodisintegration reaction is given by
$$\gamma\  + d\rightarrow n \ + \ p$$
I'm trying to find out the minimum energy of gamma photon $E_\gamma$ so that the reaction can occur. Writing the energy and momentum conservation equation gives
$$\frac{E_\gamma}{c}=p_p+p_n  \ \ \ \text{momentum conservation}$$
$$E_\gamma +m_{d}c^2=\sqrt{(p_nc)^2+(m_nc^2)^2}+\sqrt{(p_pc)^2+(m_pc^2)^2} \ \ \ \text{energy conservation}$$

Further, the binding energy equation can be written as
$$B_d=m_pc^2+m_nc^2-m_{d}c^2$$
I started solving these equations but It goes messing. Further, I don't understand what condition should I put for $E_\gamma$ to be minimum. Can anyone help me through this?

Answer (score 0):

To break up deuterium you need to supply, at a minimum, a photon energy equal to the binding energy of deuterium. This is about 2.225 MeV. The minimum $\gamma$ energy is equal to the binding energy.  Your last equation provides the solution.

Comment: But violate the momentum conservation. I want an exact expression.

Comment: if the proton and neutron have 0 kinetic energy, conservation of momentum at the binding energy is conserved.

Comment: How come? As suggested by the book this is not true.